# Select from with boolean functions

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, jpql

I am trying to develop an application with Java EE. Here is a part of my class diagram which I want to to implement:

[image]

Here is the implementation of classes with hibernate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_enseignant")
public class Enseignant extends User implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String specialite;
    private List<Module> modules;

    public Enseignant() {
    }

    public Enseignant(String nom, String prenom, String email, String login, String password, String specialite) {
        super(nom, prenom, email, login, password);
        this.setSpecialite(specialite);
    }

    public String getSpecialite() {
        return specialite;
    }

    public void setSpecialite(String specialite) {
        this.specialite = specialite;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "enseignant")
    public List<Module> getModules() {
        return modules;
    }

    public void setModules(List<Module> modules) {
        this.modules = modules;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_classe")
public class Classe implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;
    private String niveau;
    private int nbreEtudiant;

    private List<Module> modules;

    public Classe() {
    }

    public Classe(String niveau, int nbreEtudiant) {
        this.niveau = niveau;
        this.nbreEtudiant = nbreEtudiant;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

...
```

I also implemented the Module Class and ModulePK.
I want to check that a teacher should be assigned to a class once.
I tried with the following JPQL query

```
boolean exists = false;
    String jpql = "select case when (count(m) > 0)  then true else false end  from Module m where m.idEnseignant=idEnseignant and m.idClasse=idClasse";
    TypedQuery<Boolean> query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql, Boolean.class);
    query.setParameter("idEnseignant", enseignant.getId());
    query.setParameter("idClasse", classeToValidate.getId());
        exists = query.getSingleResult();
```

but when I execute the method I have this exception

```
could not resolve property: idEnseignant of: domain.Module [select case when     (count(m) > 0)  then true else false end  from domain.Module m where m.idEnseignant=idEnseignant and m.idClasse=idClasse]
```

Comment: Please show class domain.Module

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to the `:` to indicate your named parameters, so you had `idEnseignant=idEnseignant` instead of `idEnseignant=:idEnseignant`

Here's the corrected code:

```
boolean exists = false;
String jpql = "select case when (count(m) > 0)  then true else false end  from Module m where m.idEnseignant=:idEnseignant and m.idClasse=:idClasse";
TypedQuery<Boolean> query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql, Boolean.class);
query.setParameter("idEnseignant", enseignant.getId());
query.setParameter("idClasse", classeToValidate.getId());
exists = query.getSingleResult();
return exists
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Module` entity you define `modulePk` to be the primary key. There are two possiblities to use this id:

- Create an instance of `ModulePk` class and pass it to the `find()` method of the entity manager (which is not the case in your query), or
- To use it in JPQL query you have to traverse the embedded id class. In your case use it as follows:

  ```
  String jpql = "select case when (count(m) > 0)  then true else false end  from Module m where m.modulePk.idEnseignant = :idEnseignant and m.modulePk.idClasse = :idClasse";
  ```

Answer (score 0):

@jens

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_module")
public class Module implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private ModulePk modulePk;
private String nomModule;
private int nbreHeure;
private Enseignant enseignant;
private Classe classe;

public Module() {
}

public Module(String nomModule, int nbreHeure, Enseignant enseignant, Classe classe) {
    this.nomModule = nomModule;
    this.nbreHeure = nbreHeure;
    this.enseignant = enseignant;
    this.classe = classe;
    this.modulePk = new ModulePk(enseignant.getId(), classe.getId());
}

@EmbeddedId
public ModulePk getModulePk() {
    return modulePk;
}

public void setModulePk(ModulePk modulePk) {
    this.modulePk = modulePk;
}

public String getNomModule() {
    return nomModule;
}

public void setNomModule(String nomModule) {
    this.nomModule = nomModule;
}

public int getNbreHeure() {
    return nbreHeure;
}

public void setNbreHeure(int nbreHeure) {
    this.nbreHeure = nbreHeure;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idEnseignant", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Enseignant getEnseignant() {
    return enseignant;
}

public void setEnseignant(Enseignant enseignant) {
    this.enseignant = enseignant;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idClasse", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Classe getClasse() {
    return classe;
}

public void setClasse(Classe classe) {
    this.classe = classe;
}
```

}

and this is ModulePK class

```
@Embeddable
public class ModulePk implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int idEnseignant;
private int idClasse;

public ModulePk() {
}

public ModulePk(int idEnseignant, int idClasse) {
    this.setIdEnseignant(idEnseignant);
    this.setIdClasse(idClasse);
}
...
```